# Access Object Name and convert it to String separated by comma

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to access the list Object Names inside parent object and then convert them into String separated by comma. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: 
In this picture, under data object, I have address, phoneFax and header objects. I can have n number of objects. I'm trying to take the names of all these objects and exclude header object.

I'm expecting the output as transaction = "address, phoneFax".

Is it possible to do it with JS?

Comment: please add the data as text and what you have tried.

Comment: `keys = Object.keys(yourObject.data).filter(k => k !== 'header')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the syntax

```
for(var key in obj){
    ....
}
```

I created a simple [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mhuqo81k/). Key in your case would be data, then headers, then method, etc. So you could do what I did in the JSFiddle and only loop through the data, or you could check if the key is data and loop through that key.